# JNA: Pointer to char**

Tags: java, c++, c, jna

I own the next C function:

```
int fillWithNames(const char*** names, int *n);
```

which I convert to java using JNA proceeding like this:

```
public interface PlayersLibrary extends Library {
        PlayersLibrary INSTANCE = (PlayersLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("player", PlayersLibrary.class);

int fillWithNames(PointerByReference names, IntByReference n);

}
```

How could I print the Strings that this method returns in `names`?

I want to do something like this:

```
PlayersLibrary.INSTANCE.fillWithNames(names, n);

Pointer first = names.getValue(); // char**
String a = first.getPointer(0).getValue() // char*
System.out.println(a);
```

but in this case, `names.getValue()` returns null and I don´t know what to do

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Before even writing one line of Java, have you been able to make your function work by calling it from C++?  or C?  I'm asking this, since "triple star" programming is error prone, let alone trying to interface Java to such a thing.

Comment: Hello @PaulMcKenzie, yes I have checked that the function works in C++. It's a legacy library I have

Comment: If you're getting a `null` value back from `Pointer.getValue()`, it means that the callee never wrote to the space you gave it.  Perhaps you were supposed to give it the address of an integer for the `n` parameter so that it could tell you how many it filled in?  Include the code that initializes `names` and `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`names.getValue().getStringArray(0, n.getValue()])`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getStringArray(long)).

I'm inferring that the `n` parameter is telling the callee how many names to fill in.  `getStringArray()` will convert consecutive pointer values in memory into strings until it encounters a `NULL` value; if your callee doesn't terminate with a `NULL` pointer you'll need to explicitly tell it how many pointers to read (ostensibly the `n` parameter in the call to `fillWithNames()`).

**EDIT**

So the length does indeed come back in the `n` parameter.  If the callee writes a zero to that parameter, then it's telling you it has no names (which would by why you get a `null` back in the other parameter).

Comment: Hello, no, the function writes in both parameters.

And names is a pointer to a const char**, so the memory is a bit messy because it is not consecutive as in a char[][]

Comment: Is it `const char**` or `const char***`?  Big difference.  I'm inferring that the callee writes a `const char**` to the memory you pass in.  You obtain that value by calling `PointerByReference.getValue()`, at which point you should be able to extract the string array (assuming the returned pointer is not `null`).

Comment: It is a const char***, see above.

Yes, you're inferring almost well.

The function that I call allocates some memory, writes the strings, and the number of strings it wrote. A example of C code:    `const** char test; fillWithNames(&test, &n); `

Comment: @broga Record the values of the pointers in the `C` code.  Then record the values you're getting when calling your functions in the JNA code.  Are they the same values?  I'm not referring to *what* is being pointed to, but the actual pointer values themselves.  What I don't understand (pardon my ignorance) is why you didn't use `getPointer(0)` to initially get the `char**`, and instead used `getValue`.

Comment: And on the C++ side, here is sample code that attempts to duplicate your scenario.  Maybe if you change this code to fit what you're doing, possibly you are making a mistake on the C++ side (even though you say it's working).  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4afad0c59aefb836

Answer (score 0):

[Class PointerByReference](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference.html)

> Represents a reference to a pointer to native data. In C notation, `void**`.

Also, see [SO: PointerByReference not returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337395/pointerbyreference-not-returning-value).

Comment: I have checked lot of information sources before posting, thanks for your help but this kind of answers do not help. Show me the code